# Maven - skip javadoc for submodule direct build, run in for submodule when building master

Tags: java, maven

OK, so I have a quite simple structure:

```
+ root
|- submodule1
|- submodule2
|- submodule3
```

What I want to achieve is to skip javadoc when I build each submodule directly (with any goal) but to generate javadoc when I run building for root project.

I've tried profiles, set in submodules activateByDefault that skips javadoc and in master avoid it but this didn't work and either javadoc was always skipped or always generated.

Any insights how to resolve it?

Comment: can you show your `pom.xml` files?

Comment: they are kinda regular maven project files without any special settings.